# changin the default width and height of the dropdownlist

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

i want a dropdownlist that is wide enough to accommodate the larger item in the dropdown in display area of the main control.(.i.e. dropdownlist with the functionality of MX Combobox)
please guide me on this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create custom DropDownList (extending original) and override `dataProvider` setter and `measure()` method. In `dataProvider` setter you should invoke `invalidateSize()` and in measure you should iterate your data provider and find the largest label (you can assign new text to the label and compare their width).

Comment: i also thought in the sameway , but my boss told me to find anyother property to achieve this bahaviour.so please guide me about this

Comment: It seems there is no way to adjust existing properties to achieve it. Sorry.

Comment: Hehe. You can vote up or even accept answer in renumeration for it :) There was very useful answers for your question :)

Answer (score 3):

This will adjust the width of the drop down to the width of the data.
I forget where the example is where i got the code from. The height can be set by rowCount I believe.

```
package valueObjects.comboBox{

    import flash.events.Event;
    import mx.controls.ComboBox;
    import mx.core.ClassFactory;
    import mx.core.IFactory;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    public class ExtendedComboBox extends ComboBox{
        private var _ddFactory:IFactory = new ClassFactory(ExtendedList);

        public function ExtendedComboBox(){    
            super();
        }
        override public function get dropdownFactory():IFactory{
            return _ddFactory;
        }
        override public function set dropdownFactory(factory:IFactory):void{
            _ddFactory = factory;
        }
        public function adjustDropDownWidth(event:Event=null):void{    

        this.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT,adjustDropDownWidth);
            if (this.dropdown == null){
                callLater(adjustDropDownWidth);
            }else{
                var ddWidth:int = this.dropdown.measureWidthOfItems(-1,this.dataProvider.length);
                if (this.dropdown.maxVerticalScrollPosition > 0){                    
                    ddWidth += ExtendedList(dropdown).getScrollbarWidth();                    
                }                
                this.dropdownWidth = Math.max(ddWidth,this.width);                
            }
        }
        override protected function collectionChangeHandler(event:Event):void{
            super.collectionChangeHandler(event);
            this.addEventListener(FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT,adjustDropDownWidth);        
        }
    }
}



package valueObjects.comboBox{
    import mx.controls.List;

    public class ExtendedList extends List{
        public function ExtendedList(){
            super();
        }
        public function getScrollbarWidth():int{
            var scrollbarWidth:int = 0;
            if (this.verticalScrollBar != null){
                scrollbarWidth = this.verticalScrollBar.width;
            }
            return scrollbarWidth;
        }

    }
}




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" mlns:comboBox="valueObjects.comboBox.*" >

  <comboBox:ExtendedComboBox labelField="data.totext()" itemRenderer="mx.controls.Label" />
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: In flex 3 ,if we don't specify width and height of the combobox,then the width of the combobox is wide enough to accommodate the larger element in dropdownlist . now we have seperate dropdownlist control in flex 4 .if we don't specify the width and height to dropdownlist , then it will take 112 pixel as width (default width). my requirement is ,if i don't specify the width and height of the dropdownlist , it should be wide enough to accommodate the larger content in its popup. please suggest me on this

Comment: That is exactly what the class files do that I posted in my answer. Have you even tried to use them yet?

Answer (score 2):

To increase the height of a combo box's drop-down list, use **"rowCount"** property. This is for Flex 3.6.0

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/01/28/setting-the-width-of-the-dropdown-menu-on-a-spark-dropdownlist-control-in-flex-4/) from Flex Examples. You just have to create a skin for the `DropDownList` and set the `popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth="false"` property.

Comment: yeah i have tried the given concept.but in flex 3 ,if we don't specify width and height of the combobox,then the width of the combobox is wide enough to accommodate the larger element in dropdownlist . now we have  seperate dropdownlist control in flex 4 .if we don't specify the width and height to dropdownlist , then it will take 112 pixel as width (default width). my requirement is ,if i don't specify the width and height of the dropdownlist , it should be wide enough to accommodate the larger content in its popup. please suggest me on this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

it is achieved by following code :

```
public override function set dataProvider(value:IList):void
    {

        var length:Number = 0;
        var array:Array = value.toArray();
        super.dataProvider = value;
        var labelName:String = this.labelField;
        var typicalObject:Object =new Object();
        for each(var obj:Object in array)
        {
            var temp:Number = obj[labelName] .length;
            if( length < temp )
            {

                length = temp;
                Alert.show(" length  "+length.toString());
                typicalObject = obj;
            }
            //length = length < Number(obj[labelName].length) ? Number(obj[labelName].length) : length
            //Alert.show(obj[labelName].length);
            this.typicalItem = typicalObject;
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, better take off both the width and height from the field.

Comment: if we remove both the height and width ,then the default height and width property are applied to dropdownlist